# What is the meaning of following ADF output

Tags: azure, azure-databricks, azure-data-factory

I am running Python notebook on Azure data factory. Which has failed and giving me following output.

```
{
    "effectiveIntegrationRuntime": "DefaultIntegrationRuntime (Central India)",
    "executionDuration": 260,
    "durationInQueue": {
        "integrationRuntimeQueue": 0
    },
    "billingReference": {
        "activityType": "ExternalActivity",
        "billableDuration": [
            {
                "meterType": "AzureIR",
                "duration": 0.08333333333333333,
                "unit": "Hours"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

What is the meaning of this output?

Comment: Hi, If my answer is helpful for you, hope you can accept it as answer. This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per my experience, it's the pipeline run consumption. It give the value which can help you
calculate the cost of the pipeline. No matter the pipeline failed or succeeded.
[image]

Ref this: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/calculator/?service=data-factory%2F

HTH.

Answer (score 0):

It means your activity ran on an Azure Integration Runtime (DefaultIntegrationRuntime in Central India) and you were billed for ~260 seconds of usage.